# Phantom image along border while dragging object in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, fabricjs2

I have a group of objects in fabric.js, everything is non evented and not selectable except a single object which I will call the selector. They are grouped together because they all need to move as one group. When this selector moves with in the bounds of the group everything works as expected. However when I moved the object outside of the bounds (even though I programmatically have it stop before that point it draws phantom objects along the edge of the main group.

I have gone through the code and commented things out and tried placing `.renderAll()` and `.setCoords()` on objects I think may be the issue but so far no luck.

Here is a short clip showing what is happening - https://i.imgur.com/bnIJWY7.mp4

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or working snippet demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Been trying to rip the code out to try to simulate this, will keep trying and post it here if I am able to duplicate it. Hoping someone might of experienced it before but will try to get a fiddle that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Alright, I am still trying to repro this issue but I found it had to do me bringing the group of items to the front with a loaded image.